# oracle rollback and commit

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

In the following sql statements:

```
BEGIN
update table1 set col1 = 'Y';
commit;
update table2 set col2 = 'Y';
rollback;
end;
/
```

Will it rollback both the updates or only update #2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just #2

You might be interested in [save points](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_savepoint.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Your statement will rollback only the current transaction. i.e. the update of table2.

You ended the update of table1 transaction when you issued a commit.

As vc74 says, save points are a useful tool for controlling where you can rollback to without having to issue commits etc.